# AppActivate for multiple processes [one application]

Tags: windows, authentication, vbscript, bots

I have a problem with VBS, AppActivate command to be exact.

==============================================

#### [Basic Info]

I'm trying to create VBS which would run my game and log me in.

#### [Self progress]

So far I was able to achieve that :

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe""")
WScript.Sleep 10000
objShell.AppActivate "League Client"
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
objShell.SendKeys ("mylogin")
objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
objShell.SendKeys ("mypassword")
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

#### [Problem 1]

This script doesn't work. 
I've tried to use it for other applications and then it works.
I started to troubleshooting and so far I have noticed that League of Legend client opens 4 processes, each has other PID (1x LeagueClient.exe, 3x LeagueClientUX.exe)

#### [Problem 2]

Selecting application by PIDs didn't work as well.

#### [Idea]

Do you know how to select League of Legends window otherwise? I should also mention that I am refering to LOL's client launcher.

Comment: `AppActivate` can be used as a boolean to check whether you successfully activated the window. You might verify the window title by pressing `Alt+Tab` and reading the text. Then you might use a loop to try to activate the window every few seconds, checking whether `AppActivate` is true in each loop.

Comment: I have tried to use even part of code to only activate already opened window and do some instructions.

Comment: It did not activated even after some sleeping time.
For apps where there is only one process it works fine, but not in this case.

Comment: It's in the documentation for SetForegroundWindow (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx). There are 8 rules and you have to comply with one of the 8 to set the foreground window. Often people spend time doing stuff, like sleeping, then try to activate a window after 2 secs have expired.